# Converting from Euler Angles to Yaw-Pitch-Roll

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

There are two applications with the following rotation specifications:

```
Houdini: Euler Angles (X, Y, Z) which go from -360 to 360
Unreal: Yaw-Pitch-Roll (X, Y, Z) which goes from -180 to 180
```

Anyhow, both systems accept as well Quaternions, so I've tried using quaternions, but they don't seem to align. They are kind of both euler angles but what are their exact terms? And how do I convert between these systems?

Sorry for my novice terminology.

Comment: Euler angles and Yaw-Pitch-Roll are basically the same thing, you know. Might be applied in a different order, but yaw, pitch and roll are just the standard names for the three components on an Euler angle.

Comment: They could be interpreting quaternions in different ways, but I would guess that it wouldn’t be hard to deduce the differences with a few tests, and then use wuaternions,

Comment: Well, i definitely started with brute forcing  and changing axis but didn't seem to work, so the one is not called "Taity-Bryan Angles" ?